# How to test express controller fetching a file with Jest

Tags: express, jestjs

I had a simple endpoint using Express to allow user to download a `csv` file.
How should I make a test with just Jest for a file download endpoint

I'm not sure which function or mock should I use to test out this scenario, as it returns with `Number of calls: 0` for below test

controller.js

```
const getFile = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=sample.csv');
    const csv = 'ID\n1\n2\n3';
    res.send(csv);
  } catch (e) {
    next(
      new HttpException(
        'internal error',
        'file download error',
        e.message,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

controller.test.js

```
test('should successfully download the csv', async () => {
      const mockReq = {};
      const mockRes = {
        send: jest.fn(),
      };
      await controller.getFile(mockReq, mockRes, jest.fn());
      
      expect(mockRes.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ 'Content-Type': 'text/csv' });
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Your `getFile` isn't returning anything, nor is it calling `next()` (the jest callback), which it should not be, or you'd get an error. You have some weird implementation here.

Comment: It should be `expect(mockRes.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith('ID\n1\n2\n3')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone face similar problem like me, I think the easiest way is using `supertest` library. This library support `HTTP assertions`, so I can test at route level:

```
const request = require('supertest');
...

const response = await request(app).get(
        '/api/.../download-file',
      );
expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
expect(response.headers['content-type']).toMatch('text/csv; charset=utf-8');
expect(response.headers['content-disposition']).toMatch(
        'attachment; filename=' + 'sample.csv',
);
```